# Which Databases Link to Particular Table in Database

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I'd like to know if there is a way to determine which databases link to a particular table in a database without looking through each database to see if it links to the database of interest.  I'm looking for a function analogous to the trace dependents function in Excel.

Comment: You could probably use Visio to create a diagram: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614